# Was Sakaki telling the truth when he said Zen is younger than Raj?

Tags: snow-white-with-the-red-hair

In volume 4 of *Snow White with the Red Hair*, Zen, Shirayuki, Kiki, and Mitsuhide had their ages revealed by the author, and Zen is said to be older than Raj. In a Volume 7 side story, however, Sakaki said that Zen is younger than Raj. Was this a lie to try and make Raj meet up with him, or was it other reasons?

Comment: Do you have any reason to doubt that Sakaki was telling the truth when he said that?

Comment: But in volume 4, Zen, shirayuki, Kiki and Mitsuhide age was revealed by the author and Zen is older. But now in volume 7, Sakaki says otherwise

Comment: Thank you, I've proposed an edit to add that context into your question. It's entirely possible the answer is just "the author forgot the characters' ages", but maybe someone who's more familiar with the manga will be able to propose an in-universe explanation.

Comment: A quick check from wiki reveals that Zen is 19 years old and [Raj is 17 years old](https://akagaminoshirayukihime.fandom.com/wiki/Raji_Shenazard). However, while the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B5%A4%E9%AB%AA%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BD%E9%9B%AA%E5%A7%AB#%E4%B8%BB%E8%A6%81%E4%BA%BA%E7%89%A9) confirms about Zen's age from volume 4, Raj's age is not mentioned anywhere. Since I'm not following the series, do you know any reference, possibly directly from the anime/manga, that Raj is 17 years old?